# Laravel Excel WithHeadingRow cannot find header index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

i have some problem that Laravel WithHeadingRow does not working.

for example, i have this kind of excel file.

| productId | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 2132 | example_name |

but i can't load rowheader using WithHeadingRow.

code:

```
class RandomRotationProductImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row): ?RandomRotationProduct
    {
        return new RandomRotationProduct([
            'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
            'product_name' => $row['product_name']
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but this cause the error: "message": `"Undefined index: product_id"`

is there anything to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

- i think name must be the same as in file .
  so it should be
- $row['productId']
- $row['productName']

Comment: I think that is not the answer. if you see this documentation: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html,

it's formatting automatically.

and i also tried your solution